# How to create a new accents notation

Tags: accents

I need use a new accents notation to denote a operation defining by myself. It is a bar with two points at the left/right end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[myaccents{A}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[\overset{\textcolor{red}{\cdot}\!-\!\textcolor{red}{\cdot}}{A}\]
\end{document}
```

Or to simplify with a `\myaccent` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\def\myaccent#1{\overset{\textcolor{red}{\cdot}\!-\!\textcolor{red}{\cdot}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[\myaccent{A}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

The vertical distance of the bar can be tuned adding a `\raisebox`. Also it could look better with smaller bar and upright characters because in italics the bars *seems* not centered. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\myaccent#1{\overset{%
\hskip0pt   
\raisebox{-.2ex}[0ex][0ex]{%   
$_{\textcolor{red}{\cdot}\text{-}\textcolor{red}{\cdot}}$%
}}{\text{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[\myaccent{t} \neq \myaccent{\i} \neq \myaccent{m} \neq \myaccent{e} \]
\[\myaccent{T} = \myaccent{I} = \myaccent{M} = \myaccent{E} \]
\end{document}

\begin{document}
\[\myaccent{t} \myaccent{m} \myaccent{M}  \myaccent{g} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

To make the bar as long of the character one could use `\widthtof{}` from package  `calc`. In the example I made this rule  `2pt` shorter due to the dots. May be should be some more shorter, but then the rule is very little in narrow characters as `\i`. Adjust as you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\myaccent#1{\overset{
\hskip0pt % add 2 or 3 pt if you change \text{#1} to #1 to use italics 
\raisebox{-.3ex}[0ex][0ex]{%   
$_{\textcolor{red}{\cdot}\rule[.35ex]{\widthof{#1}-2pt}{.4pt}\textcolor{red}{\cdot}}$%
}}{\text{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[\myaccent{t} \neq \myaccent{\i} \neq \myaccent{m} \neq \myaccent{e} \]
\[\myaccent{T} = \myaccent{I} = \myaccent{M} = \myaccent{E} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE3]

Comment: For italic letters, may be look better  `some like \overset{\hskip3pt ...`

Comment: Thanks. But your macro is not any kind of accent. For clarity just try `\myaccent{t}`. And the bar's center line is too high.

Comment: @delimeterfont You can adjust the height as you whish  with `\raisebox`. I edited the answer to insert an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question: why the bar seem so short for the letter (like m and M)? Could the bar's length change with the letter? Could the bar center between the width of the letter?

Comment: @delimeterfont Yes, with `\widthof`. Please see the edited answer again.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand the question, you need to place your accent above math variables. They are typically in italics (math italics). The `\mathaccent` primitive does the horizontal placement of the accent by kern between the base and `\skewchar`. We can simulate this behavior by macros. Then your accent will look better above italics variables.

```
\mathchardef\myskewchar="717F 

\def\myaccent#1{\vbox{\offinterlineskip \lineskip=-.066em
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\myskewchar$}\dimen0=\wd0
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\kern0pt\myskewchar$}\advance\dimen0 by-\wd0
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\dimen1=\wd0 \advance\dimen1 by-.3em
                       \ifdim\dimen1<.2em \dimen1=.2em \fi
   \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr \hbox to0pt{\hss\kern2\dimen0
       ${\cdot}\hbox to\dimen1{\leaders\vrule height .28em depth-.23em\hfil}{\cdot}$%
       \hss}\cr$#1$\cr}}}

$\myaccent A \dot A + \myaccent x + \dot x + \myaccent t + \myaccent {xx}$.
```

[image: skewchar02]

I've edited my code in order to vary the width of the accent by the width of the base.

There are three problems which are leaved as an exercise:

- to add the color of the dots (it depends on the another used macro, OPmac, xcolor.sty etc.)
- to complicate the macro in order to it woks in subscript and subsubsript, i.e to use `\mathchoice` or `\mathpalette`.
- to try to emulate the `\accent` primitive behavior above italics letters in text mode.

Comment: @wipet Thanks though I need the bar line can stretch with the variable(s).

Comment: @delimeterfont I've edited my post. Now, the bar line stretches with variables(s). But it wasn't given in the question.