# Parentheses around a diacritic

Tags: accents

Is there a way to put the diacritic into parentheses for characters like `ě` or `á`? If it were possible to shrink the parentheses around `ˇ` or `´`, then I could stack them with the letter.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This seems doable, although not entirely straightforward.  Out of curiosity, what is the meaning of such a combination?

Comment: I am writing a very condensed grammar chart for Czech conjugations. In specific cases both options, with or without the diacritic, are possible. Writing both characters would stretch the tabular a lot.

Comment: Makes sense.  Are you able to place a symbol in "diacritic position" above a letter?  Then I'd try making a new symbol of `\tiny` parentheses wrapped around a normal-sized diacritic lowered to a position just above the baseline, and then positioning this new symbol centered at diacritic height above the desired letter.  I'll try this myself later, but at the moment my state of unawakeness means I'd botch it terribly.

Comment: I would look into this thread:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203547/how-to-create-a-new-accents-notation
May be helpful to create your own type of accents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I create `\optional` to achieve the desired behavior.  I also provide (as an alternative) the `tokcycle` directives so that it automatically performs the action in a `\tokencyclexpress` pseudo-environment.  I have programmed for 3 particular diacritic marks.  You can add more to the directive, as needed.

Note the diacritic parenthesis size is controlled by the `.5` values in the `\scalebox` macros.  The vertical position of the parens can be adjusted with the `\dimexpr.5pt+\ht0` shift of the stack.  The horizontal placement of the parens is governed by the letter width, adjusted by the `-1mu` shifts.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\optional[2]{%
  \sbox0{#2}%
  \stackengine{\dimexpr.5pt+\ht0}{%
    \stackengine{\dimexpr.5pt+\ht0}{#1{#2}}%
      {\tiny$\mkern-1mu\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{.5}{(}}}$}%
      {O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
    }{\tiny$\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{.5}{)}}}\mkern-1mu$}%
    {O}{r}{F}{T}{L}%
}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Macrodirective{%
  \ifx\v#1\addcytoks{\optional}\fi
  \ifx\'#1\addcytoks{\optional}\fi
  \ifx\"#1\addcytoks{\optional}\fi
% ADD MORE DIACRITIC TESTS HERE
  \addcytoks{#1}%
}
\begin{document} 
% DIRECT SPECIFICATION OF OPTIONAL DIACRITICS
h\optional \v{e}avier th\optional \'{a}n dirt

% AUTO REPLACEMENT OF DIACRITICS WITH OPTIONAL FORM
\tokencyclexpress
h\v{e}avi\"{E}r th\'{a}n dirt%
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]